# How does the stack change step by step in this c++ program?

Tags: c++, stack

I have the following c++ program where a function returns a reference to a local variable. Can you please show me step by step what happens exactly to the stack?

```
#include<stdio.h>

double& init_pi()
{
    double pi = 3.14;
    return pi;
}

double circumference(double r, double& pi)
{
    printf("%lf\n", pi);
    return 2*r*pi;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%lf\n,", circumference(2, init_pi()));
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: As in how the computer would calculate this step by step?

Comment: Yes. I know that this piece of code is not correct and have a general idea why it is not, but I would like to see exactly what happens "behind the scene" to totally understand how the stack works and how this code can cause a problem.

Comment: You do it by yourself by debugging.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using any IDE?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Code::Blocks

Comment: @DavidHerskovics I never used Code::Blocks, but [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks) should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, the c++ standard never mentions the concept of a stack. (other than the std::stack class template, which is not what you mean here).

The standard talks in terms of functions, flow of control, local objects, heap objects and static objects.

It is entirely possible to write a c++ compiler for an architecture that does not have a stack (the old TMS 9900 series of chip for which I rote when I was a teenager springs to mind).

Your question might be better put as:

> How does the stack change step by step in this c++ program, when compiled with X compiler, with Y options for Z architecture?

For which the answer lies only in your debugger or in the assembler listing (for gcc, compile with -S option)

In truth, if you compile this program with optimisations on, there will be no stack movement at all. The entire flow will be inlined.

for example, gcc 5.3 with -O2 produces the following code (see below)

Note that because you introduced undefined behaviour by returning a reference to a local variable, the compiler is permitted to do anything it likes. In this case it decided that your program does nothing. main simply returns zero.

assembler output:

```
init_pi():
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "%lf\n"
circumference(double, double&):
        pushq   %rbx
        movl    $1, %eax
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        call    printf
        movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm1
        movsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
        addq    $16, %rsp
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm1
        popq    %rbx
        mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        ret
main:
        movsd   0, %xmm0
        ud2
```

compiler warning:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11636-75-1libuwy/example.cpp: In function 'double& init_pi()':
5 : warning: reference to local variable 'pi' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
double pi = 3.14;
^
Compiled ok
```

If we fix the warning and subsequent error, we get this:

```
init_pi():
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        ret
.LC2:
        .string "%lf\n"
circumference(double, double):
        subq    $24, %rsp
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm1, (%rsp)
        call    printf
        movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm2
        movsd   (%rsp), %xmm1
        addq    $24, %rsp
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm2, %xmm0
        mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        ret
.LC5:
        .string "%lf\n,"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        call    printf
        movsd   .LC4(%rip), %xmm0
        movl    $.LC5, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1374389535
        .long   1074339512
.LC4:
        .long   1374389535
        .long   1076436664
```

Again, you will see that `main` has been completely inlined. There is no stack use whatsoever (other than during the calls to printf)